# Загрузка страницы при нажатии Enter в DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

Имеется `ddl`, при вводе значения с клавиатуры, и последующего нажатия клавиши `Enter`, происходит переход на предыдущую страницу.
Как сделать так, чтобы он все таки выбирал итем, а не перекидывал?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишите событие [SelectedIndexCnahged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) у DDL, в котором опишите логику обработки нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Погуглил и не нашел как обработать событие клавы.